# Prove zeta-esque relationship with floor function

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm looking to show that:

$$ \frac1{1-2^{-s}} \frac1{1-4^{-s}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\left\lfloor1+\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor}{2^{ks}}$$

I've noticed $(1-4^{-s})^{-1} = (1-2^{-2s})^{-1}$ and I'm fairly certain that's somehow where the floor function comes from.

I'm stuck though on the denominator. I have the first terms of $\zeta(s)$ and $\zeta(2s)$ expressed as products of primes respectively on the left. Why do I get a $k$ in the exponent in the denominator on the right? How should I go about proving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:

$$\frac{1}{1-2^{-s}}\frac{1}{1-4^{-s}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}2^{-ns}\sum_{m\geq 0}2^{-2ms}=\sum_{k\geq 0}r(k)\, 2^{-ks}\tag{1}$$
where:
$$ r(k) = \#\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{N}^2 : a+2b = k \}\tag{2} $$
so we just need to show that $r(k)=\left\lfloor 1+\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor$.

That is pretty easy, since $r(k)$ is just the number of even numbers $\leq k$.